# How to query multiple rows which have the same tags, output all their tags and sort the result by a tag category?

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, tags, sql-order-by

I have seen this done on multiple websites, webshops but I can't figure out a correct and fast way to do it.

I have 4 tables:

```
**pv_tags:**
tag_id
tag_category_id
tag_name

**pv_tag_connections:**
tag_connection_id
tag_connection_product_id
tag_connection_tag_id

**pv_tag_categories:**
tag_category_id
tag_category_name

**pv_products:**
product_id
product_name
product_desc
```

**EDIT: [SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80d045)**

I'd like to have a single MySQL query:

- to output all the products which match for all of the custom (user chosen) tags (any number of chosen are tags possible)
- include all other tags of the products found (every product can have any number of tags)
- group by any of a user selected tag category (any number of categories possible in the future)
- sort inside these groups by the chosen category's tag names ASC or DESC

What I have tried for days now customize any of these two queries. They can both give me the results of the selected tags, but I can't make group of categories, and sort inside them. Unfortunately I have found out that while `group_concat` is good for listing all other tags, I can't make it work for grouping and sorting.

```
select * from pv_tag_connections 
INNER JOIN pv_tags ON tag_connection_tag_id = pv_tag_id
where tag_connection_product_id IN 
(
    select DISTINCT tag_connection_product_id 
    from pv_tag_connections pc 
    inner join pv_tags c on pc.tag_connection_tag_id = c.pv_tag_id
    where c.pv_tag_id in (1,46)
    group by pc.tag_connection_product_id
    having count(distinct c.pv_tag_id) = 2
)
```

AND

```
SELECT *,
group_concat(DISTINCT pv_tags.pv_tag_name ORDER BY FIELD(pv_tags.pv_tag_category_id,'5','1','2','3','4') SEPARATOR ',') AS tag_values_for_sort,
group_concat(DISTINCT pv_tags.pv_tag_id SEPARATOR ',') AS tag_ids
FROM pv_products
INNER JOIN pv_tag_connections pvc0 ON pvc0.tag_connection_product_id = pv_products.katalogusid AND pvc0.tag_connection_tag_id IN (1) 
INNER JOIN pv_tag_connections pvc1 ON pvc1.tag_connection_product_id = pv_products.katalogusid AND pvc1.tag_connection_tag_id IN (46)
INNER JOIN pv_tag_connections ON pv_products.product_id = pv_tag_connections.tag_connection_product_id
INNER JOIN pv_tags ON pv_tag_connections.tag_connection_tag_id = pv_tags.pv_tag_id
GROUP BY product_name
ORDER BY tag_values_for_sort DESC
```

I'm not sure which method is faster - they seemed similar to me -, I also can build them dynamically in PHP before running the query. One thing I like to avoid is creating other tables.

A sample output would be like:

```
User searches for
'red' - tag_id:4, tag_category_id:1
'shoe' - tag_id:8, tag_category_id:2
'group by' - tag_category_id:4 (in stock or not)
'sort by' - tag_category_id:3 (which is here adult, child, men, women etc.)
```

The expected result should be like

```
"Adioas" | "red" | "shoe" | "adult" | "in stock"
"Nile" | "red" | "shoe" | "child" | "in stock" | "20% discount"
"Nile" | "red" | "shoe" | "men" | "in stock" | "20% discount"
"Ribook" | "red" | "shoe" | "women" | "in stock" | "casual" | "with gift"
"Nile" | "red" | "shoe" | "adult" | "out of stock" | "20% discount"
"Adioas" | "red" | "shoe" | "men" | "out of stock"
"Ribook" | "red" | "shoe" | "women" | "out of stock" | "casual"
```

I'm starting to think that I'm missing something obvious solution.

**EDIT2**: I'm thinking about this and it seems that the these columns in the result would be enough for me:

```
product_id | product_name | group_by_tag | sort_by_tag | group_concat with all used tags for the product
```

Comment: If you show us a nice schema definition of your tables and provide some test data, you might get more action here. Alternatively create a mysql fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/ and place a link to it in your question

Comment: You are right, thank you. Updated with added SQL Fiddle.